When adding empty spaces in Powerpoint Text, sentence gets split and words are on second row
I have a simple table in Powerpoint with a table in it.

When I make the title a bit longer, it add a second line as intended

Sometimes I need to place two tables side-by-side, one with short title and the second with longer one.

Tables become misaligned and to correct I thought of adding empty spaces in the title of the first one.
But the result is that the work REPORT is going to second row.

Is there a simple way to fix this?
One option I thought of is to add dummy words with white characters.
However I would like a more elegant and correct solution.
